# Java - Unable to get the latest Edge/Chromium release working with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge, chromium

We have a set of Selenium auto tests that work with Chrome/Firefox/Edge (pre Chromium Edge). We would like to be able to run the set test suite against the latest edge.

```
Selenium (Java) - 4.0.0-alpha-4
Edge - 79.0.309.71
```

I've tried various combinations of the below setup

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.edgehtml", "false");
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "path\to\msedgedriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path\to\msedgedriver.exe");

EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
edgeOptions.setBinary("path\to\msedgedriver.exe");

driver = new EdgeDriver();
```

Each time gives the following error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-4', revision: 'c2d955b49e'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_162'
Driver info: driver.version: EdgeDriver
```

Has anyone got this working?

Comment: What is the version of Edge you have installed? Or it's the same as `edge.driver`? And this is the right way to declare path of `edge.driver` `System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "path\to\msedgedriver.exe");` (your second `setProperty`)

Comment: It's edge v79.0.309.71, with the correct matching driver from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

Comment: Have you tried to use Selenium 3.14? To be sure it's not a problem from alpha 4.0?

Comment: Also try to use newer version of java https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html (at least `8u181`)

Comment: 32 Vs 64 bit driver was the issue for me, but thanks for the comments @KunLun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will be relevant for everyone, but I have fixed it myself by doing the following...

The version of edge is Version 79.0.309.71 (Official build) (64-bit) and i assumed the correct driver was the the 64 bit driver from the microsoft site.

HOWEVER, I then tried the 32 bit driver and it worked as expected...

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "path\to\msedgedriver_32.exe");

driver = new EdgeDriver();
```

Answer (score 1):

I test with Microsoft Edge(Chromium) Beta version 79.0.309.43 and the same version of Microsoft Edge(Chromium) WebDriver (You could download the webdriver from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)) and it works. You could refer to the code below and change the path to your owns:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions; 
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeOptions;


public class Edgeauto {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "your\\path\\to\\edge\\webdriver\\msedgedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge Beta\\Application\\msedge.exe");
        EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions().merge(chromeOptions);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(edgeOptions);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

Also please remember to have the location of Edge Beta and msedgedriver.exe on your PATH.